# Is there a way to raise Permission Denied without rendering 403.html?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to raise just the status of the error. PermissionDenied automatically renders 403.html for me. Is there a way to just raise the status without this?

```
class IsMemorandumAdmin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self,user):
        permission = Permission.objects.get(
            name="Can CRUD Memorandums")
        return permission in user.user_permissions.all()

    def handle_no_permission(self,request):
        raise PermissionDenied
```

the mixin API requires me to throw an exception of BasePermission type. If possible, an HttpResponse(status=401) would be nice

Answer (score 0):

`@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated ))`
try to put that statement on your function

```
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def my_function(request):
    pass
```